# IE hangs when I open a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, internet-explorer

This is on SharePoint 2007 and I'm accessing the site from Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18537. When I go to any document library in our site, I see the below:

[image: Internet Explorer has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...]

Then...

[image: Internet Explorer has stopped working. A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.]

I don't even get a chance to open any files or folders before this error occurs and it only seems to happen on one computer (running Windows 7 Ultimate). So I think it must be a IE setting but I've tried messing around with it a bit and had no luck. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could advise on what I can do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try two things

1. Open the I.E. In enterprise-mode(compatability-mode)
2. Also disable the adds-ons. I.e SharePoint Export Database Launcher. You can start i.e. Using this command iexplore.exe -extoff

Comment: Thank you @waqas-sarwar-mcse! Turning on Compatibility mode did the trick for me. :)